# domain name not working for some ports in nginx

Tags: nginx, dns, cloudflare

I use nginx in my ubuntu server with this config:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.ir www.example.ir;
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/user/project;
}
location /download {
    rewrite ^/download$
http://example.ir/files/file.apk;
}
location /download/ {
    rewrite ^/download/$
http://example.ir/files/file.apk;
}
location /files/ {
    root /home/user/download/;
}
}



server{
    listen 8585;
    server_name example.ir www.example.ir;
        location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/project.sock;
}
}
```

I can access the site (which is in django) with IP (1.2.3.4:8585) although it is not set in nginx (I know it passes throw nginx because it shows up in nginx access log!), but I can't access it with the domain name! (it times out)
the only ports that works with both ip and domain name are 80 and 8080!!! other ports don't work.

I use cloudflare service for dns.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cloudflare only lets you use some specific ports listed here:

For requests made via HTTP:

80
8080
8880
2052
2082
2086
2095

For requests made via HTTPS:

443
2053
2083
2087
2096
8443

you can use 8880 instead of 8585 or change your dns service.

Comment: thanks for your response :))
I changed it to 8880 and it worked :))